# Consume Windows service from WebAPI

Tags: windows-services, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to consume WebAPi into windows service. Because WebAPI is http protocol, so iam not sure weather i will consume WebApi.

I tried search for consuming WebAPI with Windows service. I can't even find single examples.

Can any face similar kind of scenario

Comment: Yes we can able able to consume WebAPi inside the Windows service.  Since it is windows based service we need consume it with HttpClient object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can able able to consume WebAPi inside the Windows service. Since it is windows based service we need consume it with HttpClient object.